# What could be the code to read the default-text value inside an input text in protractor?

Tags: protractor

I want to read the default text inside an input text field. For Example: -

[Reservation Text Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZsJv.png)

I want to read - "Enter Reservation Number" from the input field. And I need to verify this text.

Here is the html value: -

```
<div class="input-field" ng-class="{'has-error': !$ctrl.isValid}">
<input id="reservation-number" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength" maxlength="30" required="" title="reservation-number" ng-blur="$ctrl.reservationModified($ctrl.reservationNumber);" ng-model="$ctrl.reservationNumber" type="text">
<label class="avoid-overlap ng-binding" for="resNumber"> Enter Reservations Number </label>
```

How can I read that using protractor?

I have tried these css value:-

1. element(by.css('.avoid-overlap.ng-binding').getText();
2. element(by.css('label.avoid-overlap.ng-binding').getText();
3. element(by.css('ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-empty.ng-invalid.ng-invalid-required.ng-valid-maxlength').getText();

Answer (score 0):

`getText()` returns a promise.

See the [documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText). An example explains how to solve it.

Comment: I have tried this but this will work only if you have provided some value in the text field. But I want to read the tip text. This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. It is working now. I tried this code:-

```
element(by.css('[for="resNumber"]')).getText();
```

And It is working fine for me.

Comment: btw. why not just `element(by.css('label')).getText();`?